# jquery get info from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying this example code to get info from another page, but unfortunatelly not work.
Can someone help me?
this is jquery code:

```
   $.ajax({
   url:href,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data){
       $('#content').html($(data).find('#content').html());
   }
});
```

Comment: The href MUST come from same origin or you will get CORS errors (look in the console)

Comment: and if it is same origin you do not need the find: `$('#content').load('page2.html #content > *')`